# Remove first comment before sentence

Tags: java, regex

I want to use java to remove comment from sentence.

Comment could be deleted when it exists in head of sentence.

such as :

```
/*comment1*/ sentence /*comment2*/  content /*comment3*/ == sentence /*comment2*/  content /*comment3*/
```

Only remove first comment

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `replace`, instead of `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst` or some other regex-related methods?  If you want a solution, you shouldn't put restrictions like that on the solution unless there's a good reason.  Have you looked into regexes at all?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes. you are right. anything method is ok and there is no restrictions on implement.  I think regex is priority selection.

Answer (score 1):

Use an anchored regex to match just the *first* comment:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^\\s*/\\*.*?\\*/\\s*", "");
```

The key points of this regex are:

- `^` means "start of input"
- `.*?` matches anything but with *reluctant* quantifier (so it doesn't match all the way to the last `*/`)

The match (if any) is replaced with a blank, which effectively deletes it.

---

Test code:

```
String str = "/*comment1*/ sentence /*comment2*/  content /*comment3*/ == sentence /*comment2*/  content /*comment3*/";
str = str.replaceAll("^\\s*/\\*.*?\\*/\\s*", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
sentence /*comment2*/  content /*comment3*/ == sentence /*comment2*/  content /*comment3*/
```

Comment: Rather than comment on effectiveness, up-vote (click the "up" triangle to the left of the answer) useful answers (voting is what drives the value of this site - good answers get voted up)